# Getting wrong output when cells have html special characters when using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet Library ( https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet ) to read uploaded excel file. The excel files contains html tags and html special characters. Im getting wrong results as my function iterate through the cells.

**Sample Code**:

```
$fileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
$objReader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objReader->setinputencoding('ISO-8859-1');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $objReader ->load($inputFile);

foreach ($spreadsheetUploaded->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $array = $worksheet->toArray();
}

var_dump($array);
```

**Output**:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "cell_1,cell_2,cell_3" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(480) "
Heading – 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum   dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
,," } }
```

**Expected Output**:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "cell_1" [1]=> string(6) "cell_2" [2]=> string(6) "cell_3" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(472) "
Heading - 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } }
```

Take Note that cell 1 contains html special character " – " equivalent to '&#8211+semi-colon'

**Excel File Used**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdLJsEmnIXiL0xPEl0J2np0fLP9gl41twk3yNHl3DzI/edit?usp=sharing

**File's Format**: Csv

Comment: So exactly what format is this file?

Comment: @mark The file's format is Csv

Comment: My guess is that PHPSpreadsheet is identifying it as an HTML file rather than as csv, because it contains a significant proportion of html markup.... try explicitly using the csv Reader

Comment: @mark  Thank you for looking into this, I tried updating the code to use csv reader. Please see snippet below

$objReader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
$objReader->setinputencoding('ISO-8859-1');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $objReader ->load($inputFile);

But i'm still getting the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update to latest develop version oh PhpSpreadsheet, specificaly after [that commit](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/commit/139d85d87435d0ff11d24a2070c5846f8b73a53e).

Then, the following code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$csv = <<<STRING
cell_1,cell_2,cell_3
"<h2>Heading &#8211; 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",,
STRING;

$file = 'test.csv';
file_put_contents($file, $csv);
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($file);

var_dump($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray());
```

will correctly output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "cell_1"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "cell_2"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "cell_3"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(478) "<h2>Heading &#8211; 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>"
    [1] =>
    NULL
    [2] =>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @PowerKiKi, Thanks for looking into this, Im currenlty using the latest version. One thing i noticed is that my csv file looks like this: 

`cell_1,cell_2,cell_3
"<h2>Heading &#8211; 2</h2><p>...`

On your example, i'm not sure what the "STRING" stands for on the $csv variable. But when I added an empty string ( equivalent to empty row ) before and after the csv it now has a correct ouput.

`#next line added before the first line
cell_1,cell_2,cell_3
"<h2>Heading &#8211; 2</h2><p>,,
 #next line added after the last line`

Comment: what is the version you are using ?

Comment: Hi @PowerKiKi, It seems that I have updated the wrong installation. The version I'm currenlty at is 1.0.0.. I changed the installation to phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:dev-develop and now it's working. Thank you!